# how to extract break points created by cut_interval function in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The results of `cut_interval(c(1, 10), 5)` are as follows:

```
[1] [1,2.8]  (8.2,10]
Levels: [1,2.8] (2.8,4.6] (4.6,6.4] (6.4,8.2] (8.2,10]
```

However, I want to get the break points created by `cut_interval` as:

```
[1]  1.00  2.8  4.6  6.4  8.2  10.00
```

Is there any way to do it in R?

Comment: Notice that you have five factor levels, but are asking for a result with 6 levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the code for that function you might be led to investigate the un-exported function `breaks`:

```
> ggplot2:::breaks(c(1,10),"width",n = 5)
[1]  1.0  2.8  4.6  6.4  8.2 10.0
```